# inserting new user object into JDBC through the servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

Here is the code for my servlet which recieves username parameter from a registration form

```
String tusername=request.getParamater("un");

String dbURL="db.com";
String dbusername= "lc";
String dbpassword="lcpw";
Connection con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbusername,dbpassword);

Statement stmt= con.createStatement();

String query="SELECT * FROM users.username WHERE username=(tusername)";

ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query);

if(rs.next()==false){
  //create new userobject with value of tusername
 }
```

My question is how do I create a new user object with calue of tusername, would it be like so ?

```
if(rs.next()==false){
  Statement stmt=con.createStatament();

  String query="INSERT INTO user.username VALUE 'tusername'";
  ResultSet rs= stmt.updateQuery(query);

 }
```

I understand some of this might be archaic (such as not using a prepared statement) , I am just trying to better my understanding and I think I am having some small syntax issues, thanks :)

Comment: As your code is in a servlet, I would recommend you to register your datasource in the configuration of the servlet container (tomcat? jetty?), and obtain it with JNDI.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `NOT EXISTS` query to do the insert, and also you should ideally be using a prepared statement:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO user.username (username) ";
sql += "SELECT ? FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user.username WHERE username = ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, tusername);
ps.setString(2, tusername);
int result = ps.executeUpdate();

if (result > 0) {
    System.out.println("Inserted new user " + tusername + " into username table";
}
else {
    System.out.println("User " + tusername + " already exists; no new record was inserted");
}
```

I don't know what your actual database is.  The above should work out of the box for MySQL and Oracle.  It might need to be modified slightly for other databases.

An alternative to the above query would be to just use your current insert, but make the `username` column a (unique) primary key.  In that case, any attempt to insert a duplicate would fail at the database level, probably resulting in an exception in your Java code.  This would also be a more database agnostic approach.

Comment: A more conventional alternative is to declare a unique key in the database on username and catch the exception that happens on duplicate inserts. That would be more declarative and also work for other programs that access the table. Maybe also safer in the face of concurrency (you might need a very high isolation level to have this subquery detect conflicting inserts).

Comment: Perfect answer but what about duplicate records i.e. primary key.